# jquery получить все data атрибуты в массив

Tags: jquery

Ни как не могу понять, как правильно сделать, смысл такой на сайте есть несколько блоков с классом .active и у них есть data-sort="***" при методе $('.sort__wrapper .active').data("sort") я получаю data ТОЛЬКО первого элемента, а мне надо чтобы я получил массив из 2 элементов. Первого и второго data.
html

```
<div class="sort__wrapper">
                    <div class="sort__table table-1">
                        <div data-sort="lengvas" class="table__item">
                            <div class="check active"></div>
                            <p>Lengvas</p>
                        </div>
                        <div data-sort="vidutinis" class="table__item">
                            <div class="check"></div>
                            <p>Vidutinis</p>
                        </div>
                        <div data-sort="sunku active" class="table__item">
                            <div class="check"></div>
                            <p>Sunku</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я думаю, у вас некоторая неточность в html, `<div class="check active"></div>` здесь класс `activ` вместе с классом `check`.

А тут вы поместили в дата атрибут `<div data-sort="sunku active" class="table__item">`

Смею предположить, что должно быть так: при условии если `<div data-sort="lengvas" class="table__item active">`

```js
let a = $('.sort__wrapper .active')
let arr = []

a.map(function(index, item){ 
arr.push(item.dataset.sort);
})
console.log(arr)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="sort__wrapper">
  <div class="sort__table table-1">
    <div data-sort="lengvas" class="table__item active">
      <div class="check "></div>
      <p>Lengvas</p>
    </div>
    <div data-sort="vidutinis" class="table__item">
      <div class="check"></div>
      <p>Vidutinis</p>
    </div>
    <div data-sort="sunku " class="table__item active">
      <div class="check"></div>
      <p>Sunku</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Если должно быть так: `<div class="check active"></div>`  то

```js
let a = $('.sort__wrapper .active').parent()
let arr = []

a.map(function(index, item) {
  arr.push(item.dataset.sort);
})
console.log(arr)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="sort__wrapper">
  <div class="sort__table table-1">
    <div data-sort="lengvas" class="table__item ">
      <div class="check active"></div>
      <p>Lengvas</p>
    </div>
    <div data-sort="vidutinis" class="table__item">
      <div class="check active"></div>
      <p>Vidutinis</p>
    </div>
    <div data-sort="sunku " class="table__item ">
      <div class="check active"></div>
      <p>Sunku</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```